# Building a small home server

Tags: operating-systems

Good day everyone.

I am not sure if this was the right forum on stackexchange, but I found it most applicable.

I have quite an old PC (currently running Untangle, but not needed anymore), with limited resources. The computer currently has:

- CELERON M 360 - 1.4GHZ 400MHZ  FSB - 1MB L2 CACHE
- 256MB RAM
- 200GB HDD

What I would like to do is build it into a home server, without adding/changing any of it's components (ie without spending more money on it)

I would possibly like to:

- Use it as a file sharing server with USB support (I have an external harddrive I'd like to be able to access from anywhere within my home or simply use it as a basic file server)
- Run network monitoring tools The Dude and Wireshark on it
- Possibly run Spiceworks applications on it

I have installation disks and licences for all versions of Windows, but am afraid Windows will make the PC too slow to run anything on top of the OS. I am thinking a lightweight OS that supports Windows applications (I know it is a long shot).

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What Windows applications do you need to run? With 256MB RAM I can't think of anything "Windows" that will work that is not totally out of date security wise.

Comment: The Dude and Wireshark mostly. The Dude's technical requirment is simply "The Dude runs on most versions of Microsoft Windows. It is recommended to use Windows 2000 or newer. We have successfully used The Dude even on very low power machines, so generally, any system which can acceptably run Windows 2000 or Windows XP will be able to run The Dude."

Comment: Windows 2000, 2003 and XP are all EOL. Windows 7 or 2008 is not an option for such a machine. Wireshark runs on Linux, and I bet there are good alternatives for "the Dude" that run on Linux. My advice is to buy a Raspberry PI for $40 and use that, but I suppose you can get Linux running on that machine as well.

Comment: Pretty much all of my servers run linux.  If you run a server install of ubuntu, you don't get a GUI (although you can install one later), which in my experience frees up a significant amount of resources.  Prior to this year, that machine  just had a bunch of external USB drives plugged in to increase my storage

Comment: FYI: That Celeron is not going to handle Spiceworks well at all, especially with that little RAM. See: http://community.spiceworks.com/help/Spiceworks_Requirements

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your comments. I loaded a couple of operating systems to test compatibility and performance as well as features provided and ultimately found the following worked best:

- Windows XP Professional (Low GUI features and animations activated)
- The Dude runs just fine, using up little resources
- Wireshark runs just fine
- File sharing is slow (But according to my network monitors, it might be because of the network speed)
- As TECHIE007 predicted, SpiceWorks doesn't run AT ALL, but I created my own intranet site for ticket logging and it works like a dream

I know it is bad practice, but I also created a paging file on the external HDD to support the little RAM.